# How to create segue for a view controller to another view controller which is embedded in a navigation controller?

Tags: swift, xcode

[This is how my storyboard is linked.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Zwcp.png)
This is my segue function. Segue to priceViewController works fine, but to the other view controller keeps crashing. Receiving error 'Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x11e264a20) to 'tableViewwithSections.priceViewController'.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      if(segue.identifier == "toPriceView"){
           let des = segue.destination as! priceViewController
           des.currentCity = String(self.cityLabel.text!)
      }
      if(segue.identifier == "toTableView"){
           let des = segue.destination as! tableViewController
           des.currentCity = String(self.cityLabel.text!)
      }
 }
```

Comment: Can you share the exception stack

Comment: Is your tableViewController actually called that? In your image it looks like Saved Locations or something like that? Also in your “toTableView” if statement you are referencing a property of the priceViewController. Why is that? Unconnected but fwiw your view controllers are objects and as such (in Swift) should start with a capital letter.

Comment: I’ve just reread everything. Your first line is forcing the segue destination to be a priceViewController before you test the segue identifier. That causes a crash when you are triggering the tableViewController Segue.

Comment: Yes sorry, made edits to the post. I removed that first line but still running into that error. I suspect that it has something to do with the fact that the tableViewController(which is titled Saved Locations) is embedded in the navigation controller. Not sure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had something like this originally and as far as I can see it should work. You need to access the `tableViewController` through the `UINavigationController`.

```
if(segue.identifier == "toTableView"){
     let nc = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
     let des = nc.topViewController! as! tableViewController
     des.currentCity = String(cityLabel.text!)
 }
```

Comment: ahh ok it works. It seems that i didnt try this after I initially removed the first line. Thank you very much for your time and help!!!